# How to establish a connection between two computers wirelessly?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

Maybe is my question a little bit weird, but I am looking for an answer since couple days.
The only thing what I found were sockets and asyncio(dont really know what it is) , but with sockets you can establish a connection just in your localhost.
Is there any otherways to creat a connection between two quite different pcs or between a client and server wireless.

If you have any ideas just write, maybe it could be helpful. As a beginner in python, I would be happy if you guys could show me some way to find easy tutorials (maybe some websides) and important things to learn. So everything could be helpful, I am just curious. `:)`

Comment: you can use socket on TCP IP see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html to connect between 2 computers

Comment: Set up Wi-Fi then use sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a server / client pair, through executables running on both PCs. TCP and UDP sockets ***can*** be used to communicate outside 'localhost'. You can do this rather easily in many programming languages like C, C#, python amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create two seperate python files: client.py and server.py
The client.py will be trying making the connection. the server.py will be trying to receive that connection. You mentioned you weren't familiar with socket. Socket is a low-level networking interface when you import the library socket to a file, you are able to make system calls between different computers to interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ros library form [here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation) for example if you have Ubuntu 16.04.

after that it is very easy to use [those lines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

We used this method with robots.